# Require all policies by default in Api Controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-authorization

I don't know if this may sound stupid, but I'm a bit worried about how authorization is done in Controllers.

Right now I'm using [Authorize] attribute to secure my end points. But, I'm a bit worried I forget to add a policy and anyone could access the end point.

Is there any way to apply all policies by default and just add an attribute forthe ones you want to allow?

Comment: An authorization policy consists of one or more requirements. It's registered as part of the authorization service configuration in the `Startup.ConfigureServices `method.Then policies are applied to Controllers by using the `[Authorize(Policy = "PolicyName")]` attribute with the policy name. Refer to [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: I know how this works. And I'm using it like that. But, I prefer somehitng that offers security by default. I mean, A controller wihtout an [Authorize] attribute should disallow accessd to any action. Then, Later I will add an attribute to a method to signal that I want an user with policy X to be allowed to use that method. By default Controllers allows access to any controller action without restriction. I just want it to be the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.Net Core 2.x you can use a filter to set a global Authorization Attribute:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // This requires an authenticated user for all controllers/actions, 
    // except when at controller/action the [AllowAnonymous] attribute is set.
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

    // In the same way you can set a global AntiforgeryToken
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

In Asp.Net core 3.x endpoint routing is introduced. When enabled you can set this per endpoint, as described in the [migration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authorization-for-specific-endpoints):

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
```

with possible endpoint configuration:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // equivalent of [Authorize] attribute on each controller:
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();
});
```

Not asked, but recommended: [Automatically validate antiforgery tokens for unsafe HTTP methods only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatically-validate-antiforgery-tokens-for-unsafe-http-methods-only).